# Достигнуто максимальное значение пула

Tags: c#, mysql, timeout, pool

Подскажите пожалуйста, как решить вопрос с соединением. Использую базу данных MySQL, в программе к ней куча различных запросов. В какой то момент выводит сообщение:

```
Timeout expired. The timeout period elapsed prior to obtaining a connection from the pool. This may have occurred because all pooled connections were in use and max pool size was reached.
```

Не знаю как быть, очень надеюсь на ваш опыт и помощь

Comment: См. напр. https://www.connectionstrings.com/all-sql-server-connection-string-keywords/, особое внимание параметру `Max Pool Size`.

Answer (score 4):

Примерный перевод ошибки:

> Истек тайм-аут. Период ожидания получения свободного соединения из пула. Эта проблема может проявляться потому что все подключения в пуле в данный момент заняты и достигнут максимальный размер пула.

Если вы получаете такое сообщение, для начала надо проверить, не забываете ли вы освобождать используемые подключения к БД. Проверьте, что все подключения освобождаются либо через `using`, либо через явный вызов `.Close()`. Если используется явный вызов Close - убедитесь так же, что ваша программа всегда доходит до этой строчки.

Если вы все проверили но ошибка все еще возникает - значит, вы и правда используете слишком много соединений с БД либо держите их слишком долго. Вот что можно попробовать:

1. Не держите соединения долго, по возможности создавайте отдельное на каждую операцию. Помните, что создание соединения с БД в C# - очень дешевая операция, потому что на самом деле оно берется из пула.
2. Если вы используете фоновые задачи для доступа к БД - проверьте, что вы не создаете их слишком много.

   Так, если вы в цикле запрашиваете какие-то данные из БД - убедитесь что прошлый вопрос успел отработать к тому времени когда вы делаете следующий.

   Если вы просто делаете много фоновых запросов к БД - организуйте очереди запросов, и обрабатывайте их фиксированным числом обработчиков. Или используйте библиотеку TPL Dataflow, которая умеет ограничивать степень параллельности.
3. Если ничего не помогает - можно просто увеличить максимальное число соединений в пуле. Это делается настройкой `maximumpoolsize=...` в строке соединения (скорее всего, я не знаю какой драйвер вы используете). Более подробно параметры строки соединения можно увидеть в документации на используемый вами драйвер или на сайте https://www.connectionstrings.com/

PS этот ответ актуален для любых СУБД, не только для MySQL

Comment: Спасибо! Сейчас буду разбираться